# Efficiency/speed for trigonometric functions

Tags: performance, geometry

In a game I'm making, I've got two points, pt1 and pt2, and I want to work out the angle between them. I've already worked out the distance, in an earlier calculation. The obvious way would be to arctan the horizontal distance over the vertical distance (tan(theta) = opp/adj).

I'm wondering though, as I've already calculated the distance, would it be quicker to use arcsine/arccosine with the distance and dx or dy?

Also, might I be better off pre-calculating in a table?

Comment: You might want to check your link -- and stop playing games at work!  :-)

Comment: "Big O"?? Please don't call everything related to efficiency by that denomination. Calculation will be O(1). But that doesn't mean a thing, it definitely doesn't mean it'll be fast.

Comment: Ok, changed the title. Sorry, still picking this stuff up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to be doing this **many** times, pre-calculate in a table.  Performance will be much better this way.

Comment: Since the data would have to be normalized before doing a lookup in the table and you would probably also need to interpolate between tabulated values, pre-calculation is not a clear-cut win, unless there's a speed-accuracy trade-off that can be made acceptable.

Comment: Since it is a game - the accuracy may not be as important as the speed.

Comment: Pre-calculating isn't necessarily faster on a modern CPU. It depends much on things like cache misses.

Comment: There's also a trade off between table size and computational complexity. In that you can make the table bigger, which will save you computation, or you can make it smaller and then do some extra calculations to get the right value. Like you would only generate one octant of values for a table used in sin/cos/tan functions, and then do some arithmetic to figure out the index of the table.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect there's a risk of premature optimization here.   Also, be careful about your geometry.  Your opposite/adjacent approach is a property of right angle triangles, is that what you actually have?

I'm assuming your points are planar, and so for the general case you have them implicitly representing two vectors form the origin (call these v1 v2), so your angle is

theta=arccos(dot(v1,v2)/(|v1||v2|))  where |.| is vector length.

Making this faster (assuming the need) will depend on a lot of things.  Do you know the vector lengths, or have to compute them?  How fast can you do a dot product in your architecture.  How fast is acos?   At some point tricks like table lookup (probably interpolated) might help  but that will cost you accuracy.

It's all trade-offs though, there really isn't a general answer to your question.

[edit: added commentary]

I'd like to re-emphasize that often playing "x is fastest" is a bit of a mugs game with modern cpus and compilers anyway. You won't know until you measure it and grovel the generated code.  When you hit the point that you really care about it at this level for a (hopefully small) piece of code, you can find out in detail what your system is doing.  But it's painstaking. Maybe a table is good.  But maybe you've got fast vector computations and a small cache. etc. etc. etc.    It all amounts to "it depends". Sorry 'bout that.  On the other hand, if you *haven't* reached the point that you really care so much about this bit of code... you probably shouldn't be thinking about it at this level at all.  Make it right. Make it clean (which means abstraction as well as code). Then worry about the overhead.

Comment: Really not clear why this answer is so highly rated.  Given his math, the questioner appears to be looking for the angle from pt2 makes if pt1 is the local origin, and atan2 is the obvious solution (maybe with a lookup table optimization).  simon's answer is the angle sweep from pt1 to pt2 from the point of view of the origin, a completely different problem.

Comment: Sol: well, the question isn't worded very clearly, so I talked about the general case (and noted to check the geometry). I'd sort of hoped for a clarification.  Either way, though,  you're missing the point a bit; even if atan2 was the obvious approach, OP's point was that already knowing the distance this might not be fastest (which is true) and wanted the quickest approach.  It's this last bit that's really not obvious.

Answer (score 10):

Aside from all of the wise comments regarding premature optimization, let's just assume this is the hotspot and do a frigg'n [benchmark](http://pastebin.com/CwN9DH1M):

[image: bar char]

Times are in nanoseconds, scaled to normalize 'acos' between the systems.
'acos' simply assumes unit radius i.e. `acos(adj)`, whereas 'acos+div' means `acos(adj/hyp)`.

System 1 is a 2.4GHz i5 running Mac OS X 10.6.4 (gcc 4.2.1)
System 2 is a 2.83GHz Core2 Quad running Red Hat 7 Linux 2.6.28 (gcc 4.1.2)
System 3 is a 1.66GHz Atom N280 running Ubuntu 10.04 2.6.32 (gcc 4.4.3)
System 4 is a 2.40GHz Pentium 4 running Ubuntu 10.04 2.6.32 (gcc 4.4.3)

Summary: Relative performance is all over the map.  Sometimes atan2 is faster, sometimes its slower.  Very strangely, on some systems doing acos with a division is faster than doing it without.  Test on your own system :-/

Answer (score 5):

Tons of good answers here.

By the way, if you use `Math.atan2`, you get a full 2π of angles out of it.

I would just do it, then run it flat out. If you don't like the speed, *and if samples show that you're actually in that code most of the time and not someplace else*,
try replacing it with table lookup. If you don't need precision closer than 1 degree, you could use a pretty small table and interpolation.

Also, you may want to memoize the function. Why recompute something you already did recently?

Added: If you use a table, it only has to cover angles from 0-45 degrees (and it can be hard-coded). You can get everything else by symmetry.

Comment: My only complaint with this answer is "Tons of good answers here."  Nonsense, this is the only decent one.  I'd give it a +8 if I could.

Comment: @Sol: I'm flattered, though I think most of the other answers are good, and I don't always say that.

Answer (score 1):

From a pure speed standpoint, a precalculated table and a closest-match lookup would be best. It involves some overhead, of course, depending on how fine-grained you need the angle to be, but it's more than worth it if you're doing this calculation a lot (or in a tight loop), as those are going to be expensive calculations.

Comment: If you need it *really* fine-grained, you'll probably end up in the realm where interpolation, even linear interpolation for "smooth" functions as sine/cosine, works really well. No need for a huge table, at all.

Comment: Lookup-tables aren't necessarily faster.

Comment: @gs: no, but many times they are (if not, they wouldn't be very popular at all). Granted that for some calculations and some hardware, they aren't faster. For typical desktop computers and trig functions, AFAIK they win. I don't know if GPU code tricks can be used to do the work faster - if so, great (but that's a totally different trick!).

Answer (score 1):

Get it right first !
And then profile and optimize. Table lookup is a good candidate for sure, but be sure to have your calculation right before doing anything fancy

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're interested in big-O notation, all the methods you might use are O(1).
2. If you're interested in what works fastest, test it.  Write a wrapper function, one that calls your preferred method but can be easily changed, and test with that.  Make sure that your application spends a noticeable amount of time doing this, so you aren't wasting your own time.  Try whatever ways occur to you.  Ideally, run it on more than one different CPU.

I've become very leery of predicting what will take more or less time on modern processors.  Lookup tables used to be the answer if you needed speed, but you don't know a priori the effects on caching or how long it's going to take to normalize and look up versus how long it's going to take to do a trig function on a particular CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is for a game, you probably care about speed.  A lookup table is definitely the fastest but you trade accuracy for speed with this method.  So how accurate must you be to meet requirements?  Only you can answer that.  Before you trade accuracy, determine first if you have a speed problem.  All of the trigonometric functions are calculated using numerical methods (research numerical analysis to learn more).  Some trig functions are have more expensive methods than others because they rely on series that converge more slowly and who knows, your computer may have different implementations for these functions than another computer.  At any rate, you can find out for yourself how expensive these functions are by writing some small programs that loop through as many iterations as you desire, with increments of your choosing, all the while timing the outcomes.  Then you can pick the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

While others are very right to mention that you are almost certainly falling into the pit of premature optimization, when they say that trigonometric functions are O(1) they're not telling the whole story.

Most trigonometric function implementations are actually O(N) in the value of the input function. This is because the trig functions are most efficiently calculated on a small interval like [0, 2π) (or, for the best implementations, even smaller parts of this interval, but that one suffices to explain things). So the algorithm looks something like this, in pseudo-Python:

```
def Cosine_0to2Pi(x):
    #a series approximation of some kind, or CORDIC, or perhaps a table
    #this function requires 0 <= x < 2Pi

def MyCosine(x):
    if x < 0:
         x = -x
    while x >= TwoPi:
         x -= TwoPi
    return Cosine_0to2Pi(x)
```

Even microcoded CPU instructions like the x87's `FSINCOS` end up doing something like this internally. So trig functions, because they are periodic, usually take O(N) time to do the argument reduction. There are two caveats, however:

1. If you have to calculate a ton of values off the principal domain of the trig functions, your math is probably not very well thought out.
2. Big-O notation hides a constant factor. Argument reduction has a very small constant factor, because it's simple to do. Thus the O(1) part is going to dominate the O(N) part for just about every input.

Comment: There is no way that "Most trigonometric function implementations are actually O(N) in the value of the input function."

You can do a simple benchmark.